# length of a character pointer not correct using strlen()

Tags: c++

i made my own length function which runs perfect for a normal character array but in case of pointers it doesn't give correct results. same happend with strlen() function.
let's say i stored "books" in Pointer character array a. it should display 5 as length then why does it show 14

```
char * regrowchar(char *p, int size)
{
    char *q = p;
    p = new char[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        p[i] = q[i];
    return p;
}

void input(char *a, int &size)
{
    int i = 0;
    cin >> a[i];
    while (1)
    {
        size++;
        a = regrowchar(a, size);
        i++;
        cin.get(a[i]);
        if (a[i] == '\n')
        {
            a[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int size1 = 1;
    int size2 = 1;
    char * a = new char[size1];
    char * b = new char[size2];

    input(a, size1);
    input(b, size2);

    cout << strlen(a) << "   " << strlen(b) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please provides specific information about the problem that you are having and what you mean by "not giving correct results". What are the results you are expecting and what results are you getting?

Comment: lets say the pointer array had "books" stored in it, the strlen() function gives 14 as output when the length is clearly 5.

Comment: Print the strings, not their lengths.

Comment: Code, input, observed behaviour, expected behaviour. Some of those are missing.

Comment: Off topic but... `a = regrowchar(a, size)` will cause all memory pointed to by `a` before the call to be leaked.

Comment: *How* did you input "books" in this code? `cin >> a[i];` only accepts a single `char`

Comment: UnholySheep yes i took one character 'b' then in the while loop the cin.get() gets remaining characters

Comment: The argument `a` (a pointer) is passed to `input()` by value.  So the change `a = regrowchar(a, size)` is not visible to `main()`.  Pass it by reference.  Also, although you haven't asked, your code leaks memory, since it dynamically allocates but never deallocates.

Comment: wow thanks peter! it worked! :)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The argument `a` (a pointer) is passed to `input()` by value. So the change `a = regrowchar(a, size)` is not visible to `main()`. Pass it by reference. Also, although you haven't asked, your code leaks memory, since it dynamically allocates but never deallocates.
by https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter

Comment: Did you really just copy a comment and post it as answer? That is plagiarism

Comment: oh sorry my bad forgot to mention him :)